# How to Build Oleo on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, compile

I am trying to install Oleo (http://www.gnu.org/software/oleo/) on a Cygwin setup and am running into some issues. In the linking stage, the build errors out, complaining about undefined references in ncurses. I have the libncurses-devel packages installed.

The commands I ran to build were:

```
me@mymachine$ CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/ncurses" ./configure
[configure chatter, then success]
me@mymachine$ CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/ncurses" make
[snip successful compile...]
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1ef8): undefined reference to `_ncwrap_stdscr'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1f08): undefined reference to `_wattrset'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1f45): undefined reference to `_printw'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1f6c): undefined reference to `_printw'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1f71): undefined reference to `_ncwrap_stdscr'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1f81): undefined reference to `_wattrset'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x1fa6): undefined reference to `_printw'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x206c): undefined reference to `_printw'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x20da): undefined reference to `_printw'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x21b2): undefined reference to `_printw'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x21c9): undefined reference to `_ncwrap_stdscr'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x21df): undefined reference to `_wmove'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x21ec): undefined reference to `_ncwrap_stdscr'
io-curses.o:io-curses.c:(.text+0x21f4): undefined reference to `_wrefresh'
```

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing these ncurses issues?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `-lcurses` or `-lncurses` to CFLAGS for successful compiling.